# Sorting array of hashes based on multiple values

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have an array of hashes:

```
[ 
  {
    :title=>"Working as a SSE",
    :organisation=>{:id=>428, :name=>"google"},
    :from=>"2018-6-1",
    :to=>nil
  }, {
    :title=>"Concatenate two video files to single video in players",
    :organisation=>{:id=>197, :name=>"UNFPA"},
    :from=>"2014-1-1",
    :to=>"2015-12-1"
  }, {
    :title=>"Highcharts Demo",
    :organisation=>{:id=>6, :name=>"UNDFS"},
    :from=>"2016-1-1",
    :to=>"2017-6-1"
  }, {
    :title=>"Working as a Judicial Affairs",
    :organisation=>{:id=>427, :name=>"swtp"},
    :from=>"2017-1-1",
    :to=>"2018-6-1"
  }
]
```

I want to sort it in the following order:

1. First sort is based on `to`
2. Second sort is based on `from`
3. Third sort is based on  `organisation name`
4. Finally, sort based on `title`

Can anyone help me sort the array of hashes?

Comment: Where does `nil` of `:to=>nil` go? Please answer with edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
arr = [ 
  {
    :title=>"Working as a SSE",
    :organisation=>{:id=>428, :name=>"google"},
    :from=>"2018-6-1",
    :to=>"2017-6-1"
  }, {
    :title=>"Concatenate two video files to single video in players",
    :organisation=>{:id=>197, :name=>"UNFPA"},
    :from=>"2014-1-1",
    :to=>"2015-12-1"
  }, {
    :title=>"Highcharts Demo",
    :organisation=>{:id=>6, :name=>"UNDFS"},
    :from=>"2016-1-1",
    :to=>"2017-6-1"
  }, {
    :title=>"Working as a Judicial Affairs",
    :organisation=>{:id=>427, :name=>"swtp"},
    :from=>"2017-1-1",
    :to=>"2018-6-1"
  }
]
```

```
arr.sort_by { |h| [h[:to], h[:from], h[:organisation][:name], h[:title]] }
  #=> [{:title=>"Concatenate two video files to single video in players",
  #     :organisation=>{:id=>197, :name=>"UNFPA"},
  #     :from=>"2014-1-1",
  #     :to=>"2015-12-1"},
  #    {:title=>"Highcharts Demo",
  #     :organisation=>{:id=>6, :name=>"UNDFS"},
  #     :from=>"2016-1-1",
  #     :to=>"2017-6-1"},
  #    {:title=>"Working as a SSE",
  #     :organisation=>{:id=>428, :name=>"google"},
  #     :from=>"2018-6-1",
  #     :to=>"2017-6-1"},
  #    {:title=>"Working as a Judicial Affairs",
  #     :organisation=>{:id=>427, :name=>"swtp"},
  #     :from=>"2017-1-1",
  #     :to=>"2018-6-1"}]
```

See [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), particularly the third paragraph of the doc, and [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

Comment: 1+ for passing number of arguments to `sort_by`